# is there a way to query an entire list inside a document in flutter firebase?

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, chat, documentation

I am building an app with a chat feature, and now I am trying to show all the last history tickets. I have a user database that stores all of the current user room chat, I fetched it to List currentUserRoomList.

```
// Getting a stream of the chat
  getChatStream() {
    return chatRef
        .doc(currentUserRoomList.first) // << here
        .collection('messageId')
        .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .snapshots();
  }

  // Build the story tickets here
  buildStoryTickets() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getChatStream(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return loading();
        }
        List<ChatHistory> tickets = [];
        snapshot.data.docs.forEach((doc) {
          ChatHistory ticket = ChatHistory(
            id: doc.data()['id'],
            otherUserId: doc.data()['otherId'],
            message: doc.data()['message'],
            photoUrl: currentUserId == doc.data()['id']
                ? doc.data()['photos'][1]
                : doc.data()['photos'][0],
            displayName: currentUserId == doc.data()['id']
                ? doc.data()['names'][1]
                : doc.data()['names'][0],
            rid: doc.data()['rid'],
            timeStamp: doc.data()['timeStamp'],
          );
          tickets.add(ticket);
        });
        return ListView(children: tickets);
      },
    );
```

chatRef is from another page. ->

```
final chatRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('chatrooms');
```

I have in chatRef all of the rooms ids in the app.
My problem is with getChatStream(),
It working when I give it only 1 value(
for example: .doc(currentUserRoomList.first)),
but I am trying to build history tickets for all the values in currentUserRoomList and I am struggling with that.
Thanks in advance!